# How to make `List<T>` type to work with EF?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

How to make `List<T>` type to work with EF ?

```
public class EntityA {
    public string Id {get;set;}
}

public class EntityB {
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public List<EntityA> Items {get;set;} // <---
}
```

Comment: Code first? Database First?

Comment: List<t> works since ef4 and perhaps earlier. Add virtual to the definition.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to follow conventions set by Entity Framework. I don't see what exact version of EF you are using but instructions from this URL should work for you:

[Entity Framework Code First Conventions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx)

Comment: @Code0987 Then just follow instructions from that page I gave, namely for lists something like -> public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }

Comment: Read the docs, and found 'virtual' keyword was missing and had to change entities according to conventions. Thanks.